# How do you distinguish the sender of mouse up event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to implement a click-like event using preview left button down and up for controls that do not have a built-in click event. (e.g `TextBox`)

The problem is when the mouse is moved outside of the control `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event is still fired as if the control sent it.

1. Mouse down inside of the control. (let's say control A)
2. User moves the mouse outside of control A while pushing the left button.
3. User releases the mouse outside of control A.

Since the pointer of the mouse is not in control A, the sender of `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` must be something else than control A.

What I'm experiencing is the sender always be control A in the situation I describe.

Is this an intended operation?
If it is the way it works, how can I distinguish the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event that is fired inside of control A from that is fired from outside?

Comment: What you are seeing is what is called _Capture_ in the Win32 world. When the mouse down happens  the control _captures_ the mouse. That way, when the user moves off the control, it can react appropriately, and when mouse-up happens, is the control that gets to determine what happens. Once the world returns to normal (after mouse-up), the capture is released. Think about what would happen if that procedure wasn't followed

Comment: @Flydog57 Is it possible mouse can be captured without calling a capture-related function or setting a variable that is related to capturing?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the relative position of cursor from `MouseEventArgs` and then check if it is inside its event source.

```cs
private static bool IsMouseEventInsideElement(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is not FrameworkElement element)
        return false;

    var cursorPosition = e.GetPosition(element);

    return (0 <= cursorPosition.X && cursorPosition.X <= element.ActualWidth)
        && (0 <= cursorPosition.Y && cursorPosition.Y <= element.ActualHeight);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a great way to solve my problem. But I still want to know if this is normal behavior or if something wrong makes this happen.